# BananaPI M2 Ultra boot stuck at "Scanning for Btrfs filesystems"

Tags: boot, btrfs, bananapi

Is there a way to skip this phase? Is it possible to force board to boot from SD card again?

I have BananaPI M2 Ultra v1.1 board and my goal is to get this little device boot Linux OS from its eMMC storage. So I entered URL https://www.armbian.com/bananapi-m2u/, connected board with keyboard, display and ethernet switch and downloaded image (Bookworm CLI). Then I followed document at https://docs.armbian.com/User-Guide_Getting-Started/ and was able to get my board boot from SD card. Then I made configurations as guided and lastly proceeded installation to eMMC. Then I made poweroff, took SD card out and started board. Boot started nicely but sadly stuck at stage "Scanning for Btrfs filesystems".

I read also document at https://docs.armbian.com/User-Guide_Recovery/ but it didn't help.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I chose ext4 filesystem when doing installed into eMMC.

EDIT:
And booting from this same SD card fails if I flash it again.